# C method gives warning: expression result unused and freezes

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have small problem with my home task. I have to create a method that sums an array, but with specific, given step. I did something like this:

```
int sum_step(int t[], int size, int step)
{
   int i;
   int sum = 0;

   for(i=0; i < size; i+step)
   {
      sum += t[i];
   }

   return sum;
}
```

and console returns warning:

```
warning: expression result unused
  [-Wunused-value]
  i + step;
  ~ ^ ~~~~
```

Someone knows what is wrong? Thank in advance!

Comment: Note: C does not support _methods_. Only _functions_. And the error message does not match the shown code. See [ask] provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, note that there are two flavours of 'freeze' - 0% CPU, (blocked), and 100% CPU, (looping).  It's very useful to know which you have!

Comment: Not to sound mean, but did you double check your code when your compiler gave you a warning?  It's sort of an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In following `for` statement the third expression `i+step` does nothing.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i + step)
```

You probably want `i` to be incremented by `step` after each iteration so you should write this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i += step)
```

Comment: The code in the message is not the same as the one shown. Notice the semicolon!

Comment: @Olaf the `;` might be part of the error message, I'm not familiar with gcc.

Comment: Yeah, the message output was from a slightly different code (I tried with `i+step;` at the end. Sorry for that. But Michael was right i missed `=`.

Comment: It would be strange adding syntax elements for the output line. I can assure you, gcc does not add something to the output line.

Comment: But still with `for (i = 0; i < size; i += step)` it gives me some weird numbers from array...

Comment: @MikołajKlimas in that case you must post another question, giving the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: @MikołajKlimas please ask another question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).